# Velocity smoother and navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, husky, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,

I am working on a project with clear-path husky and i am trying to get velocity smoother and navigation stack to work together. Any advise or suggestions to make it work?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216655/velocity-smoother-and-navigation-stack/) by [rohit.ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/23233/rohit.ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The velocity_smoother simply prefilters an command input based on some acceleration constraints. Documentation here: http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_velocity_smoother

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0